# Unknown filesystem, grub rescue

Tags: grub2

When I try to boot I get this message:
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

results of:
grub rescue> ls

Is as follows:

(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)

Comment: Can you post the output you get when you run `root '(hd0,msdos1)'` and `ls /`?

Comment: It shows Unknown command